# Stacked bar using GChart with Java and GWT?

Tags: java, gwt, gchart

Could anyone help me with the code needed to get a stacked bar using gchart with Java under google web toolkit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot at the moment create stacked bars using [gchart](http://code.google.com/p/clientsidegchart/) with [Google Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) using Java.

Answer (score 1):

You can under gchart 2.7:  http://clientsidegchart.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/googlecode/gchart/client/package-summary.html#ChartGallery

Scroll down to the stacked chart with example code (it's basically a square pie chart).